# Delete nodes and attributes in xml using dbms_xmldom in oracle 9i

Tags: oracle, attributes, nodes, oracle9i, xmldom

I need using the package dbms_xmldom modify the XML as follows:

- If the value of the attribute only numbers, then this attribute is removed
- If not only the numbers, the drive to upper case
- If after modifications or initially has no tag attributes, then it should be removed
- In the root tag must add tag `<MODIFICATIONS nums="" chars="" del_tags=""/>`

where

- **nums** specify the number of deleted attributes with numbers
- **chars** to specify the number of attributes with non-digits, which are given to upper case
- **del_tags** - the number of remote tag

that is, for example, should be so:
XML input

```
<? xml version = "1 .0" encoding ="windows-1251" standalone ="yes"?>
<ROOT a="000" b="aacckf" d="75" f="69">
    <SEAL c="12"/>
</ROOT>
```

we have to remove the attributes a = "000", d="75", f="69", c = "12" and attribute b = "aacckf" changed to b = "AACCKF" and remove the tag :

```
<? xml version = "1 .0" encoding ="windows-1251" standalone ="yes"?>
    <ROOT b="AACCKF">
        <MODIFICATIONS nums="4" chars="1" del_tags="1"/>
    </ROOT>
```

**I use it**

```
drop table xmldom_table;

create table xmldom_table(
num_id integer,
before_xml clob,
after_xml clob
);

insert into xmldom_table
( num_id, before_xml )
values
(1, '<? xml version = "1 .0" encoding ="windows-1251" standalone ="yes"?>
    <ROOT a="000" b="aacckf" d="75" f="69">
        <SEAL c="12"/>
    </ROOT>');

create or replace function isnumber( p_string in varchar2 ) return boolean
  is
          not_number exception;
          pragma exception_init( not_number, -6502 );
          l_number number;
          l_return boolean := FALSE;
  begin
          if (instr(p_string,',') > 0 )
          then
                  l_number := to_number( p_string, '999g999g999g999g999g999d999999999999999999' );
          else
                  l_number := to_number( p_string );
          end if;
          return TRUE;
  exception
          when not_number
          then
                  return FALSE;
  end;
```

**This I found and modified and stuck on this**

```
DECLARE
  g_doc dbms_xmldom.DOMDocument; -- basic DOM-document
  g_node dbms_xmldom.DOMNode;
  new_node dbms_xmldom.DOMNode;
  new_el dbms_xmldom.DOMElement;
  g_nlist dbms_xmldom.DOMNodeList; -- list of child nodes
  g_clob clob;
  g_cnum integer default 0;
  g_cchar integer default 0;
  g_cdeltags integer default 0;

  -- The procedure for withdrawal of the attributes of a node
  procedure show_node_attributes (p_node in dbms_xmldom.DOMNode)
  is
    l_nattrs dbms_xmldom.DOMNamedNodeMap; -- the list of attributes node
    l_node dbms_xmldom.DOMNode; -- the type of node - the attribute
    elem dbms_xmldom.DOMElement;
    tmp_Attr dbms_xmldom.DOMAttr;
    l_sattrs varchar2 (2000) -- Name of the attribute
    l_vattrs varchar2 (2000) -- the value of the attribute
  begin
    -- Get the attributes of a node
    elem: = dbms_xmldom.makeElement (p_node);
    l_nattrs: = dbms_xmldom.GetAttributes (p_node);

    -- Display the names of the attributes and their values ​​on one line
    if not dbms_xmldom.isNull (l_nattrs) then
      dbms_output.put_line ('length' | | dbms_xmldom.GetLength (l_nattrs));
      for i in 0 .. dbms_xmldom.GetLength (l_nattrs) -1 loop

        l_node: = dbms_xmldom.item (l_nattrs, i);
        l_sattrs: = dbms_xmldom.GetNodeName (l_node);
        l_vattrs: = dbms_xmldom.GetNodeValue (l_node);

        dbms_output.put_line ('before value:' | | i | | '' | | l_sattrs | | '' | | l_vattrs | | '' | | dbms_xmldom.getNodeType (l_node));
        if (isnumber (l_vattrs)) then
           dbms_output.put_line ('value:' | | l_sattrs | | '' | | l_vattrs);
           -- Dbms_xmldom. SetNodeValue (l_node,'');
           tmp_Attr: = dbms_xmldom.getAttributeNode (elem, l_sattrs);
           tmp_Attr: = dbms_xmldom.removeAttributeNode (elem, tmp_Attr);
           dbms_output.put_line ('deleted length' | | dbms_xmldom.GetLength (l_nattrs));
           g_cnum: = g_cnum + 1;
        else
           dbms_xmldom.setNodeValue (l_node, upper (l_vattrs));
           g_cchar: = g_cchar + 1;
        end if;

      end loop;
      -- Dbms_output. Put_line ('attrs:' | | l_sattrs);
    END IF;
  END;

  -- A recursive procedure for constructing the DOM tree of the document
  procedure recursive_tree (p_node in dbms_xmldom.DOMNode)
  is
    l_nlist dbms_xmldom.DOMNodeList; -- list of child nodes
    l_node dbms_xmldom.DOMNode; -- the current node
    l_nval varchar2 (2000) -- the value of the node
  begin
    -- Open the node description
    -- Dbms_output.put_line ('start:' | | dbms_xmldom.getNodeName (p_node));
/ *
    -- If the value of the node NULL, skip it
    l_nval: = dbms_xmldom.getNodeValue (p_node);
    if l_nval is not null then
        dbms_output.put_line ('value:' | | l_nval);
    end if;
-- * /
    -- Display the attributes of a node
    show_node_attributes (p_node);

    -- For the child node a node considered in the current
    l_nlist: = dbms_xmldom.getChildNodes (p_node);

    -- Repeat the steps you
    if not dbms_xmldom.isNull (l_nlist) then
       for i in 0 .. dbms_xmldom.getLength (l_nlist) -1 loop
          l_node: = dbms_xmldom.item (l_nlist, i);
          recursive_tree (l_node);
       end loop;
    end if;

    -- Remove the empty sites
    if (1 = 2) then
       g_cdeltags: = g_cdeltags + 1;
    end if;

    -- Close the node description
    -- Dbms_output.put_line ('Endof:' | | DBMS_XMLDOM.getNodeName (p_node));
  END;

BEGIN
   -- Building a tree
   select x.before_xml into g_clob from xmldom_table x where x.num_id = 1;

   g_doc: = dbms_xmldom.newDOMDocument (g_clob);
   g_node: = dbms_xmldom.makeNode (g_doc);

   recursive_tree (g_node);

   g_nlist: = dbms_xmldom.getElementsByTagName (g_doc, 'DOC');
   g_node: = dbms_xmldom.item (g_nlist, 0);

   new_el: = dbms_xmldom.createElement (g_doc, 'MODIFICATIONS');
   dbms_xmldom.setAttribute (new_el, 'nums', g_cnum);
   dbms_xmldom.setAttribute (new_el, 'chars', g_cchar);
   dbms_xmldom.setAttribute (new_el, 'del_tags', g_cdeltags);

   g_node: = dbms_xmldom.appendChild (g_node, dbms_xmldom.makeNode (new_el));

   dbms_xmldom.writeToClob (g_doc, g_clob);

   update xmldom_table x set x.after_xml = g_clob where x.num_id = 1;

END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written so please correct if something can be improved or corrected.

```
DECLARE
  g_doc dbms_xmldom.DOMDocument; -- basic DOM-document
  g_node dbms_xmldom.DOMNode;
  g_new_el dbms_xmldom.DOMElement;
  g_nlist dbms_xmldom.DOMNodeList; -- list of child nodes
  g_clob clob;
  g_cnum integer default 0;
  g_cchar integer default 0;
  g_cdeltags integer default 0;
  -- The procedure for manipulating the attributes of a node
  procedure manipulation_node_attributes (p_node in dbms_xmldom.DOMNode) is
    l_nattrs dbms_xmldom.DOMNamedNodeMap; -- the list of attributes node
    l_node dbms_xmldom.DOMNode; -- the type of node - the attribute
    l_elem dbms_xmldom.DOMElement;
    l_tmp_Attr dbms_xmldom.DOMAttr;
    l_sattrs varchar2 (2000); -- Name of the attribute
    l_vattrs varchar2 (2000); -- the value of the attribute
    l_nval varchar2 (2000); -- the value of the node
    l_nnam varchar2 (2000); -- the host name
    l_nattrs_len integer;
    l_nattrs_del integer default 0;
  begin
    -- Get the attributes of a node
    l_elem: = dbms_xmldom.makeElement (p_node);
    l_nattrs: = dbms_xmldom.GetAttributes (p_node);
    -- /*
    -- Manipulation with attribute values
    if not dbms_xmldom.isNull (l_nattrs) then

      l_nattrs_len: = dbms_xmldom.GetLength (l_nattrs) - 1;
      while (l_nattrs_len + 1! = l_nattrs_del) /* and (l_nattrs_len> = 0) */
       loop

        l_node: = dbms_xmldom.item (l_nattrs, l_nattrs_del);
        l_sattrs: = dbms_xmldom.GetNodeName (l_node);
        l_vattrs: = dbms_xmldom.GetNodeValue (l_node);
        -- Number - delete
        if (isnumber (l_vattrs)) then
          l_tmp_Attr: = dbms_xmldom.getAttributeNode (l_elem, l_sattrs);
          l_tmp_Attr: = dbms_xmldom.removeAttributeNode (l_elem,
l_tmp_Attr);
          l_nattrs_len: = l_nattrs_len - 1;
          g_cnum: = g_cnum + 1;
          -- Text - uppercase
        else
          dbms_xmldom.setNodeValue (l_node, upper (l_vattrs));
          g_cchar: = g_cchar + 1;
          l_nattrs_del: = l_nattrs_del + 1;
        end if;
      end loop;
    end if;
    -- */
  end;

  -- A recursive procedure for constructing the DOM tree of the document
  procedure tree_manipulation_node_element (p_node in dbms_xmldom.DOMNode) is
    l_nlist dbms_xmldom.DOMNodeList; -- list of child nodes
    l_node dbms_xmldom.DOMNode; -- the current node
    l_next_node dbms_xmldom.DOMNode; -- the current node 1
    l_del_node dbms_xmldom.DOMNode; -- delete the current node
    l_nval varchar2 (2000); -- the value of the node
    l_nnam varchar2 (2000); -- name node
    l_nlist_len number;

  begin
    -- Open the node description
    dbms_output.put_line ('start:' | | dbms_xmldom.getNodeName (p_node));

    -- Manipulation of the attributes node
    manipulation_node_attributes (p_node);

    -- Repeat the steps you
    if dbms_xmldom.hasChildNodes (p_node) then
      l_node: = dbms_xmldom.getFirstChild (p_node);
      l_next_node: = l_node;
      while not dbms_xmldom.isNull (l_next_node) loop
        if (dbms_xmldom.getNodeType (l_node) = 1) then
          tree_manipulation_node_element (l_node);
        end if;

        l_next_node: = dbms_xmldom.getNextSibling (l_node);
        if ((not dbms_xmldom.hasAttributes (l_node)) and
           (Dbms_xmldom.getNodeType (l_node) = 1) and dbms_xmldom.getNodeName (dbms_xmldom.getParentNode (l_node))! = '#document') then
          if ((not dbms_xmldom.hasChildNodes (l_node))) or (dbms_xmldom.hasChildNodes (l_node) and
(Dbms_xmldom.getNodeType (dbms_xmldom.getFirstChild (l_node))! = 1)) then
            dbms_output.put_line ('deleted: ---->' | |
                                 dbms_xmldom.getNodeName (l_node));
            l_del_node: = dbms_xmldom.removeChild (dbms_xmldom.getParentNode (l_node),
                                                  l_node);
            g_cdeltags: = g_cdeltags + 1;
          end if;
        end if;
        l_node: = l_next_node;

      end loop;
    end if;
    -- Close the node description
    dbms_output.put_line ('Endof:' | | DBMS_XMLDOM.getNodeName (p_node));
  end;

BEGIN
  for cur in (select num_id, before_xml
                from xmldom_sidor
                /* Where num_id = 4 */
                order by num_id) loop

    select cur.before_xml into g_clob from dual;

    g_cnum: = 0;
    g_cchar: = 0;
    g_cdeltags: = 0;

    -- Building a tree
    g_doc: = dbms_xmldom.newDOMDocument (g_clob);
    g_node: = dbms_xmldom.makeNode (g_doc);

    tree_manipulation_node_element (g_node);

    g_nlist: = dbms_xmldom.getChildNodes (g_node);
    g_node: = dbms_xmldom.item (g_nlist, 0);

    -- Adding a new element and attribute
    g_new_el: = dbms_xmldom.createElement (g_doc, 'MODIFICATIONS');
    dbms_xmldom.setAttribute (g_new_el, 'nums', g_cnum);
    dbms_xmldom.setAttribute (g_new_el, 'chars', g_cchar);
    dbms_xmldom.setAttribute (g_new_el, 'del_tags', g_cdeltags);
    g_node: = dbms_xmldom.appendChild (g_node,
dbms_xmldom.makeNode (g_new_el));

    dbms_xmldom.writeToClob (g_doc, g_clob);

    update xmldom_sidor x
       set x.after_xml = g_clob
     where x.num_id = cur.num_id;

    dbms_xmldom.freeDocument (g_doc);

  end loop;

END;
```